# laravel middleware within __construct

Tags: laravel, scope, middleware, laravel-middleware

I'm using https://github.com/appstract/laravel-multisite which is working fine.

Within my controllers methods, I can **var_dump** `current_site()`  and the correct information is displayed.

My issue is that within my controller `__construct` method the `current_site` function returns **null** i.e the `multi_site` object hasn't yet been setup.

```
public function __construct()
{
    //this returns null
    var_dump(current_Site());
}


public function index()
{
    //this works
    var_dump(current_Site());
}
```

I assuming the constructor is called before the routing has been done and therefore thats the issue, but I wanted to only call the `current_site` function once and have the controller know which site was being used from the start, so all methods etc would know.

I think this is just a lack of knowledge on my part rather than a code issue...any guidance ?

My route groups as like this

```
'domain' => 'dealer1.'.config('multisite.host'),
'as' => 'dealer1.',
'middleware' => 'site:dealer1'
```

I know this is todo with middleware not being done before the __construct being called but should I call it by doing

```
  $this->middleware('CurrentSite');
```

wWhat step should I do next?

Edit

I've changed my code to

```
 public function __construct()
    {



        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            //this dumps correctly
            var_dump(current_Site() );
               $this->currentSite = current_Site();
            return $next($request);
        });
        //this is null
       //var_dump($this->currentSite);
       //die("here");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        var_dump(current_Site());

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware

Hope this helps!

Comment: That does dump the current data out...but when i try    $this->currentSite = current_Site();     the property is null

Comment: @JimPhillips Even though `var_dump($this->currentSite)` is written after the middleware it's still being run before the middleware closure. It doesn't work for the same reason that your helper function didn't work before you put it inside the middleware closure.

Comment: `$this->currentSite` should be set if/when you try and use it in one of your controller methods

Comment: I think that might do the trick...I dont understand how the code you added works but I will look it up..thanks

Comment: @JimPhillips It's because you're passing a closure to the `middleware()` method. This closure is not called straight away but instead stored in an array and then called later with the rest of your app's middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Rwd is  there any way i can use this in laravel 5.1! as there isn't any default way to use this clouser!

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Are you using the multisite package as well?

Comment: @Rwd, No, but i am also having a scenario where i need to use this Clouser just like you answered here.. Which is not available in laravel 5.1

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed I would definitely suggest creating a new question as it sounds like it's going outside the scope of this one.